# $n \in \mathbb{N} \ 5|\ 2^{2n+1}+3^{2n+1}$

Tags: arithmetic, divisibility

show for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, 
$$5|\ 2^{2n+1}+3^{2n+1}$$

Indeed,

we've to show that : $2^{2n+1}+3^{2n+1}=0[5] $

note that $2^{2n+1}+3^{2n+1}=2.4^n+3.9^n= $

Comment: Note that any sequence of the form $a_n=A\cdot4^n+B\cdot9^n$ satisfies the recurrence $a_{n+2}-13a_{n+1}+36a_n=0$ with $13=4+9$ and $36=4\cdot 9$. This isn't great for a proof unless you are allowed to cite it, but interesting to know.

Answer (score 4):

You're basically there!! Now work modulo 5:

$2^{2n+1} + 3^{2n+1} = 2.4^n + 3.9^n \equiv 2.(-1)^n + 3.(-1)^n \equiv 5.(-1)^n \equiv 0$ (mod $5$)

Answer (score 2):

Its much simpler, $3\equiv -2 \pmod 5$.
So $$2^{2n+1} +3^{2n+1}\equiv 2^{2n+1} +(-2)^{2n+1} =2^{2n+1}-2^{2n+1}=0 \pmod 5$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\,k\,$ odd $\,\Rightarrow  a\!+\!b \mid a^k\!+b^k$ by Factor Theorem, or by $\,{\rm mod}\ a\!+\!b\!:\ a\equiv -b\,\Rightarrow\, a^k \equiv (-b)^k \equiv -b^k$

Answer (score 2):

Write $2^{2n+1}+3^{2n+1} = 2^{2n+1}+(5-2)^{2n+1}$ and note that $(5-2)^{2n+1}$ expands to $5t-2^{2n+1}$.

Comment: That's essentially @Rene's answer without congruences.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by induction. For $n=0$, we have 
$$2^{2n+1}+3^{2n+1}=2+3=5$$
which is divisible by $5$. Now suppose that 
$2^{2k+1}+3^{2k+1}$ is divisible by $5$, i.e. 
$$\tag{1}2^{2k+1}+3^{2k+1}=5N$$
for some integer $N$. Now consider 
$$2^{2(k+1)+1}+3^{2(k+1)+1}=4\cdot 2^{k+1}+9\cdot3^{2k+1}=
4\cdot (2^{k+1}+3^{2k+1})+5\cdot 3^{2k+1}=5(N+3^{2k+1})$$
where the last equality follows from $(1)$, which is divisible by $5$.